# Summarizing in R changing data output

Tags: r, dplyr, summarization

I am trying to summarize a type of product, where it is split each element with a "-". The code can be seen below:

```
testAct <- pipeline %>%
    group_by(Unique.Opportunity.ID) %>%
    filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(Company.Name, Sales.Team) %>%
    summarize(Product.Family = paste(c(Product.Family), collapse="-"))
seqAct <- testAct %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(Product.Family) %>%
    summarize(count = n())
```

The output is shows the "product.family" variable as '1-6', where is should be something like 'FDS-RDS'... I am not sure why it is converting it into integers.

> ```
>                           Company.Name             Sales.Team Product.Family
>                                 <fctr>                 <fctr>          <chr>
>                              Example1               Americas             1-6
>                              Example1               Americas             1-7
>                              Example1                WEMEA 2             8-7
>                              Example1                    CEE         3-3-4-7
>                              Example1                WEMEA 1             7-7
>                              Example1               Americas             1-6
>                              Example1                WEMEA 1             7-7
>                              Example1                WEMEA 2             8-7
>                              Example1                    CEE         3-3-6-4
> ```

Any assistance on this would be very helpful!

Comment: If you convert your dataframe to a tibble by sticking in `pipeline %>% as.tibble %>%`, does this let the original values carry through?

Comment: @JensLeerssen this didn't allow the original values to carry through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is tough to say without you doing a dput of the data, if you could, please add to your question the output from:

```
dput(head(df,20))
```

My guess is that the variables are factors and it for some reason is writing down the number associated with the factor. On the column you are referencing, I would do this before running my code:

```
df$column <- as.character(df$column)
```

Again. tough to help without seeing the data.

Comment: Attempted the character coalesce but no luck. Also the dput resulted in a huge output, breaking down each column structure.

Comment: I did as.character on the original dataframe and it worked! Thank you for the help, it was converting the original column from a factor to a character, thus changing the output.

Comment: @Zeke yes correct you need to change the original column to character. Glad it worked! Additionally, if you post the huge dput output, we can put the data into our version of R and test to make sure we are delivering the best solution to you, which is why I asked.